# jQuery accordion does not work on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

I have used a `jQuery` `accordion` in my website ; it is properly working on Windows and Android devices but it does not work on iPhone devices.

My `jQuery` code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var accordion;

    jQuery(document).click("ready", function(){
        accordion = jQuery("#accordion").accordion();
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to get using `click` event on a document, but did you try simple `ready` event:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

Or this (from jquery ui docs):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```